# How can I format date in string in Java15?

Tags: java, string, date, format, java-15

I have a problem about showing date in the defined format in string text.

It throws an error which is shown below after the app runs.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: Y != java.lang.String
```

How can I solve it out?

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```
String exampleFourText = 
                """
                <html>                  
                   <body>               
                     <p> %s </p>
                     <p> %.1f </p>
                     <p> %d </p>
                     <p> %c </p>
                     <p> %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td </p>
                   </body>              
                </html>                 
                """;
        
        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15 , 'y', new Date());
        
        System.out.println(exampleFourText);
```

Comment: Where does `formatted` come from?

Comment: @fantaghirocco it is a new feature of Java15.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about it

Comment: @Pshemo 15 is already shown in %d

Comment: @Pshemo What format type do I use?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). i haven’t check, but I bet that it works with `formatted()` too, so you need to change nothing but `new Date()` to `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used the wrong ordinal for the argument. It should be `%5` instead of `%1` because `new Date()` is the 5th argument.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleFourText = """
                <html>
                   <body>
                     <p> %s </p>
                     <p> %.1f </p>
                     <p> %d </p>
                     <p> %c </p>
                     <p> %5$tY-%5$tm-%5$td </p>
                   </body>
                </html>
                """;

        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15, 'y', new Date());

        System.out.println(exampleFourText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p> Hello </p>
     <p> 1234.6 </p>
     <p> 15 </p>
     <p> y </p>
     <p> 2021-03-17 </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, the idiomatic way to do it is by using `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleFourText = """
                <html>
                   <body>
                     <p> %s </p>
                     <p> %.1f </p>
                     <p> %d </p>
                     <p> %c </p>
                     <p> %s </p>
                   </body>
                </html>
                """;

        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15, 'y',
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()));

        System.out.println(exampleFourText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p> Hello </p>
     <p> 1234.6 </p>
     <p> 15 </p>
     <p> y </p>
     <p> 2021-03-17 </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleFourText = """
                <html>
                   <body>
                     <p> %s </p>
                     <p> %.1f </p>
                     <p> %d </p>
                     <p> %c </p>
                     <p> %5$tY-%5$tm-%5$td </p>
                   </body>
                </html>
                """;

        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15, 'y', LocalDate.now());

        System.out.println(exampleFourText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p> Hello </p>
     <p> 1234.6 </p>
     <p> 15 </p>
     <p> y </p>
     <p> 2021-03-17 </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned earlier, the idiomatic way to do it is by using a date-time formatter type which is `DateTimeFormatter` for the modern date-time API. However, since your desired format is also the default format of [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--), you do not need `DateTimeFormatter` for this format. Just for the sake of completeness, I have also shown the use of `DateTimeFormatter` in the following code.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleFourText = """
                <html>
                   <body>
                     <p> %s </p>
                     <p> %.1f </p>
                     <p> %d </p>
                     <p> %c </p>
                     <p> %s </p>
                   </body>
                </html>
                """;

        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15, 'y', LocalDate.now());    
        System.out.println(exampleFourText);

        exampleFourText = exampleFourText.formatted("Hello", 1234.6, 15, 'y',
                LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)));    
        System.out.println(exampleFourText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p> Hello </p>
     <p> 1234.6 </p>
     <p> 15 </p>
     <p> y </p>
     <p> 2021-03-17 </p>
   </body>
</html>

<html>
   <body>
     <p> Hello </p>
     <p> 1234.6 </p>
     <p> 15 </p>
     <p> y </p>
     <p> 2021-03-17 </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>*  For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>